# Scope variables not updating when elements are passed onto angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have scope variables like this:

```
//initialize variables
$scope.init = function () {
    $scope.myVarA = 10;
    $scope.myVarB = 5;
    $scope.myVarC = new Date();
    $scope.myVarD = new Date();
};

//etc..
```

I have an event bound to a button that calls for `checkBackEnd()`:

```
//using angular promises
$scope.checkBackEnd = function () {

    //prepare the payload, here `myVar--` don't get updated when the user enter in new values
    var payload = "/?myVarA=" + $scope.myVarA+ "&myVarB=" + $scope.myVarB
        + "&myVarC=" + dateFormat($scope.myVarC, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss") + "&myVarD=" + dateFormat($scope.myVarD, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss");

    //send it to the api service
    apiService.calculate(payload).then... etc...
};
```

My `payload` isn't updating.  They remain the default value of when `$scope.init()` was called, no matter what I input into the UI, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

The function

```
$scope.checkBackEnd = function ()
```

should be rewritten to

```
$scope.checkBackEnd = function (myVarA,myVarB,myVarC,myVarD) {
```

Then the click button be called with

```
ng-click="checkBackEnd(myVarA,myVarB....etc"
```

For some reason `$scope.myVar` will call the defaulted values when not passed in as arguments.